# How often do "Something Happened" slot machines appear?

Tags: bitcoin-billionaire

This "Somthing Happened" slot machine is driving me crazy. I just get enough bitcoins and then I roll something bad and lose all my bitcoins.

[image: slot machine]

What determines when this comes up? And how can I avoid it?

Comment: I think there's like 2-3 minutes between them, and that there's no way to avoid them. I usually get positive things though, and if I don't I just skip it with an ad or hyperbits.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how the game decides when they appear, but you can watch a video to cancel it out, if you got a bad card, or double the effect if it is a good card.

Comment: Sometimes I can't cancel it. Eg. if I don't have internet access I can't watch the video.